# How can I find the version of Azure DevOps Services using CLI?

Tags: azure-devops

There is a need to detect the version of Azure DevOps Services and run some jobs in case there is a change in version.
UI for getting the version is https://dev.azure.com/MDTProductDevelopment/_home/About
Is there a CLI way to getting the version?

I was checking CLI commands for getting the version but could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the `az devops`, you may be able to use `az devops configure --list`, which will show all configuration settings for your instance. For the full list of admin requests, refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/devops?view=azure-cli-latest).